# Can I use Wikipedia's category tree in my website?

Tags: wikipedia

I have extracted Wikipedia's category tree, and I want to use it on a website I am working on. The category tree will be used to help users assign categories and in a few recommendation algorithms.

My question is about copyright. I did not find any terms covering the categories and their mapping, so I want to know if anyone is aware of any terms covering their use, or can I use the category tree?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The categories (and their mapping) are under the same license as the other text on Wikipedia, which is [Creative Commons Attribution Share-alike 3.0 Unported](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/deed.en).

So yes, just follow the license, and you can use it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have two queries:
1. Is it ok if I attribute it to Wikipedia (as I do not know the names of all authors of all the categories), and provide a link to the Wikipedia website, and this license?
2. Since these categories will mostly be used in drop-downs, and in article pages on my website. Can I drop the attribution link next to the categories in my article pages?

Comment: @kumar If you want the official answer of how to attribute, go to https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/legalcode and look at section 4c, in particular the points (i) through (iv).